# Naming convention for getters/setters in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans, getter-setter

if I have the following private member:

```
private int xIndex;
```

How should I name my getter/setter:

```
getXindex()
setXindex(int value)
```

or

```
getxIndex()
setxIndex(int value)
```

EDIT: or

```
getXIndex()
setXIndex(int value);
```

?

Comment: Name your field "indexX" or whatever else, your problem is solved... don't overcomplicate things - even if `setxIndex` is the correct way for Beans, having method named `setxIndex` increases the *WTF factor* of the code without giving you anything in return. If your car driver is sick, don't think how to fix the car, replace the driver.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
getxIndex()
setxIndex(int value)
```

if you want them to be used as properties according to section ***8.8: Capitalization of inferred names*** of the [JavaBeans API specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) (e.g. access them via ${object.xIndex} in a JSP.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about it: http://dertompson.com/2013/04/29/java-bean-getterssetters/

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Section 8.8 refers to capitalization of a property name inferred from the method name.  This question is asking about the reverse process of naming the method based on the property name. The javadoc for Inspector.decapitalize() states that it is a "method to take a string and convert it to normal Java **variable name**", not method name as in this case.

Comment: Trust me, it is correct. In the meanwhile even all the IDEs are generating these getters and setters correct (IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans, ...)

Comment: The specification states `we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone.` In the case of `xIndex`, only the first one is. How am I misreading this (I assume I am)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the sentence from the spec you quote takes about _upper_ case. Hence, it shouldn't apply here.

Comment: you have to think “the other way around”:

If you would make the getter getXIndex the decapitalize method would look at XIndex and decide there is nothing to decapitalize – so it returns XIndex and this property does not exist.

Comment: actually this is a wrong answer .. the correct answer is getXIndex();
"The method name must have a prefix
of set/get/is, followed by the first
letter of the property in uppercase, followed
by the rest of the property name." JAVA SE 8 OCA

Comment: @Mahmoud Turki! It's indeed the correct answer. I named the property of `cDate`, `getCDate()` and i got `PropertyNotFoundException`: **Property [cDate] not readable on type**.

Answer (score 10):

In accordance with [JavaBeans API specification from 1997](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf)
it should be as Thomas Einwaller describes:

```
// According to JavaBeans API specification
public int getxIndex() { return xIndex; }
public void setxIndex(int xIndex) { this.xIndex = xIndex; }
```

This is unfortunate, *getx* and *setx* are not words. In the rare case when this would form a word or acronym it would be disinformative, eg the method `setiMessage` most
likely has nothing to do with [SETI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_for_extraterrestrial_intelligence).
Using [the only valid measurement of code quality](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m) (WTFs per minute),
I assess that **this is bad code**.

If we modify this to follow the convention for
[naming a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) it would be:

```
// According to Java naming convention
public int getXIndex() { return xIndex; }
public void setXIndex(int xIndex) { this.xIndex = xIndex; }
```

Why does the JavaBeans specification violate the convention? It all comes down to this sentence of the JavaBeans specification:

> However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are
> both upper case and if so leave it alone.

Exactly what kind of use of all upper-case names this refers to is unclear to me. Field names should, according to
[convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming), be camel cased. It seems
to me that we generate unconventional method names in order to support unconventional field names as decided by a
20+ year old document.

It should also be noted that even though it seems to be an overwhelming support for the JavaBeans specification in tools,
it is not exclusively used. Eg. Kotlin will not recognize `xIndex` as a property in the above example. Reversely, the
Kotlin property `var xIndex = 0` will result in the Java methods `getXIndex` and `setXIndex`. This seems to be a bug
according to the JetBrains support, but I fail to see how they can fix that without making a breaking change.

Some tools that does support the JavaBeans specification has not always done so, eg [Jackson](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/653)
and [Swagger Code Generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/445) have been patched to conform to it.
Even though IntelliJ generate accessors according to the JavaBeans specification, the [example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-getters-and-setters.html#d258091e78)
in the documentation differs from it. Probably because people don't know about the standard and naturally prefers the
normal method naming convention.

*So when should we follow the JavaBeans specification?* When property names should be inferred by accessors by tools that
rely on this standard, then we might want to use it. For instance, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) will rely
on the property `xIndex` being accessed through `getxIndex` and `setxIndex` methods unless we use annotations.

*When should we avoid this standard?* Per my recommendation: When the code should be read and understood by humans.
Because to not use proper camel casing when naming methods is disinformative.

If I would have it my way, we would use normal naming conventions, ie `getXIndex` and `setXIndex`. But, given the state
of things, the best solution I see is suggested by @vaxquis:

> Name your field "indexX" or whatever else, your problem is solved... don't overcomplicate things - even if setxIndex
> is the correct way for Beans, having method named setxIndex increases the WTF factor of the code without giving you
> anything in return.

Any comments regarding the JavaBeans specification should, according the specification itself, be sent to
java-beans@java.sun.com.

Comment: I'd use `setXIndex` and add a BeanInfo class to deal with this unintuitive corner case of the spec, if `setIndexX` isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
getXIndex()
setXIndex(final int xIndex)
```

Comment: If this is the right answer, why IDEs (tested Intellij, read Eclipse too) generate something else? They generate getxIndex() and setxIndex(). Can someone clarify?

Comment: not correct, those getters are not conform with the Java Bean naming conventions

Comment: This answer is not correct, the one from @ThomasEinwaller is, because this is clearly specified, and not something we need to argue about :)

Comment: @kctang! because the right way to name the property is what [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146215/3960315) is wrote. I named the property of `cDate`, `getCDate()` and i got `PropertyNotFoundException`: **Property [cDate] not readable on type**.

Answer (score 1):

Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  Introspector.decapitalize from package java.beans and you have no problem beacause it is compliant with java rules.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse ide automatically generates setters and getters as:

```
getxIndex()
setxIndex(int value)
```

Which is according to the java beans API specification.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out the problem I encountered. I named the property of `cDate`, `getCDate()` and i got `PropertyNotFoundException`: **Property [cDate] not readable on type**. So The correct answer is:

```
public int getxIndex(){...}
public MyClass setxIndex(final int xIndex){...}
```

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146215/3960315) has explained more.

Answer (score -2):

I think `getXindex()` is the best way. The getter should start with 'get', followed by the member name, with its first letter capitalized. Also the latest conventions I heard of, say that we should avoid multiple capital letters one after another. For example `getHTMLtooltip` is wrong. it should be `getHtmlTooltip` instead. Also you should try to make all your members `final` and there should not be a need of setters, since the class will be immutable ;)

Comment: @m_pGladiator: re immutable: while this is obviously desirable, not all classes can be made immutable. but of course: setters should only be present if needed. @Simon: the main reason is thread safety. if a class is immutable, no problems of concurrent modification through separate threads can ever arise

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the "javabeans" tag. The beans architecture presumes getters and setters and does not favor immutability

Comment: Downvote, as the case mentioned in the question is specified in the spec, see other answers.