# Java find setters and getters by reflection

Tags: java, reflection, setter, getter

i have a class like this

```
public class Student
{

    private String reference;
    private String aPlaceAt;
    //methods generate by Netbeans Eclipse generates the same methods
    public String getaPlaceAt(){return aPlaceAt;}
    public void setaPlaceAt(String aPlaceAt){this.aPlaceAt = aPlaceAt;}    
    public String getReference(){return reference;}
    public void setReference(String reference){this.reference = reference;}       
}
```

later i need to find the setters and getters by each property by `reflection` i am using the following code

```
public Method findSetterFor(final Class clazz,final String propertyName) throws Exception
{
    return new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName,clazz).getWriteMethod();
}

for(final Field field:clazz.testClazz.getDeclaredFields())
System.out.println(field.getName()+" "+clazz.findSetterFor(clazz.testClazz,field.getName()));
```

they return the correct setter for reference but for the property *aPlaceAt*

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: isAPlaceAt
```

why isAPlaceAt? not should be

```
public void setaPlaceAt(String aPlaceAt){this.aPlaceAt = aPlaceAt;}?
```

or why i am doing wrong? how can accomplish it thanks?

i think the setters and getters are generate correctly according to other post at SO and this link

[Link](http://dertompson.com/2013/04/29/java-bean-getterssetters/)

the methods are generate by `Netbeans and Eclipse and intellij`

**UPDATE**
here is another hot forum about it this same problem please check it out

[Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

Your getter/setter names don't follow the Java bean naming conventions ([or maybe the do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java)). For `PropertyDescriptor`, according to the javadoc

> Note that the property name should start with a lower case character,
>   which will be capitalized in the method names.

they should be

```
public String getAPlaceAt() {
    return aPlaceAt;
}

public void setAPlaceAt(String aPlaceAt) {
    this.aPlaceAt = aPlaceAt;
}
```

The error message is kind of misleading. The introspector will try to find `getAPlaceAt` and then `isAPlaceAt`. It will report the last thing it tried but failed.

You can avoid such mistakes by generating setters/getters through the IDE.

Comment: they are generate by netbeans

Comment: @chiperortiz Hmm. Netbeans isn't following bean naming conventions then.

Comment: @chiperortiz You need to also change the getter as shown in my answer.

Comment: seems to works now.. but i have 2 questions.. why eclipse and netbeans and intellij creates the setters in that way.. and hibernate using projections searchs the same methods signature only this `PropertyDescription` use this way.....

Comment: hey @Sotirios Delimanolis please check my edited  question thanks a lot.

Comment: @chiperortiz Yeah, that link has some contradictory information. Within a JSP, the proper name would be `getaPlaceAt()`, but with `PropertyDescriptor`, the javadoc states `Note that the property name should start with a lower case character, which will be capitalized in the method names.` Is the specification wrong or is the implementation wrong? I don't know.