# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException, why does xAxis not match with getXAxis

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, el

EL 2.2 in Tomcat 7 throws

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'xAxis' not found on type ...
```

when I try to access the following propery

```
private XAxis xAxis;

public XAxis getXAxis() {
  return xAxis;
}
```

like so

```
${bean.xAxis}
```

in a JSP.

In my understanding of both the JavaBeans and the EL spec `getXAxis` is the proper accessor for the `xAxis` property. Lombok agrees with me, it also generates a `getXAxis` method. The "Getter and Setter" generator in Eclipse, however, disagrees as it generates `getxAxis`.

**Update**

I meanwhile found out a few things:

- there's a ['won't fix' issue for Lombok](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=722) for this case
- all 3 major IDEs seem to generate `getxAxis`
- there's a [nice blog post](http://dertompson.com/2013/04/29/java-bean-getterssetters/) dedicated to this corner case, it's referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146215/131929 and quotes chapter 8.8 of the Java Beans spec

Still, I fail to understand how chapter 8.8 of the Java Beans spec is applicable here as it describes different cases. To me this looks much more of an implementation detail of `java.beans.Introspector#decapitalize` than a clearly defined behavior.

```
public static String decapitalize(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
        return name;
    }
    if (name.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(1)) &&
                    Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(0))){
        return name;
    }
    char chars[] = name.toCharArray();
    chars[0] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[0]);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

The spec says

> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an
>   existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower
>   case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names,
>   we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case
>   and if so leave it alone. So for example,
>
> “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
>
> “Z” becomes “z”
>
> “URL” becomes “URL”

But "if the first two characters of the name are both upper case" doesn't apply here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The spec says
>
> > Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to
> >     lower case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case
> >     names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper
> >     case and if so leave it alone. So for example,
> >
> > “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
> >
> > “Z” becomes “z”
> >
> > “URL” becomes “URL”
>
> But "if the first two characters of the name are both upper case"
>   doesn't apply here.
>
> What am I missing?

The "*existing Java name*" of your method is "getXAxis",  or it could be "isXAxis" for a boolean property.

The "*middle of an existing Java name*" is "XAxis". The "first two characters" of that are "XA", so that is left as is, without decapitalization.

There is a way to explicitly map method names onto a property name with an explicit BeanInfo, but it is rarely used.

BTW, the JavaBeans 1.01 specification is dated August 1997. It is actively used for 18 years. Download page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html

Comment: Thanks, I failed to see that `name` in `decapitalize(String name)` is the accessor method name, I thought it'd be the property name.