# Cannot find any information on property 'tax' in a bean of type 'Salary.CalSalary'?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="s" class="Salary.CalSalary"scope="page"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="s" property="sal" param="salary"/>
    <%
        s.getTax();
       %>
    <jsp:getProperty name="s" property= "tax"/>

</body>
```

**CalSalary.java**

```
import java.io.*;

public class CalSalary implements Serializable{


   private double tax,sal;

  public CalSalary()
    {

        tax=0;

        sal=0;
    }
   public void setSal(int sal1)

    {
        sal=sal1;
    }

    public double returnTax()

   {

       return tax;
   }

   public void getTax()

    {
        tax=sal*15/100;
    }

}
```

Please suggest me, where I am getting wrong?

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: couple of suggestions in the jsp page: (1) change the class to class="salary.calSalary" (2) also change scope="request"

Comment: Have you tried keeping it `public void setSal(int sal1)` `double` instead int ?

Comment: Your getters and setters must follow java bean standards i.e. getTax,  setTax,  getSal and setSal . Change the names and I think you would be OK then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java class getters and setters  must follow java bean standards . So, Try this in your class:

```
 public void setSal(double sal1){

  sal=sal1; 

 }  
 public double getSal(){

  return sal;
 }

public void setTax(double tax){
  this.tax = tax; 
 }

public double getTax(){

  tax=sal*15/100; 
  return tax;

 }
```

You could check the naming convention here :

[Naming convention for getters/setters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java)