# Variable with non-standard getter name not getting returned in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, getter-setter

I am trying to return `RemoveHoldPayload` in my API. I noticed that when I used the following getter name `isToBeClosedResult`(1) then the response is missing `toBeClosedResult` but when I change the getter name to a standard name : `getToBeClosedResult` then the variable is getting returned in the response object JSON.

Why is this happening ?

(1) : --------------

```
{
    "autoHolds": null,
    "manualHolds": null,
    "incidentId": null,
    "comment": null,
    "commentType": null,
    "error": null,
    "toBeClosed": false,
    "closeStatusCode": 0,
    "commentId": null
}
```

API: -------------

```
@PostMapping(value = "/dummyAPI")
public Object dummyAPI () throws Exception {
    RemoveHoldPayload rh = new RemoveHoldPayload();
    return rh;
}
```

CLASS : -----------

```
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveHoldPayload {
    
    private List<AggregatedHoldListResource> autoHolds, manualHolds;
    private String incidentId, comment, commentType, toBeClosedResult,error;
    private boolean toBeClosed;
    private short closeStatusCode;
    private Integer commentId;
    
    public String getToBeClosedResult() {
        return toBeClosedResult;
    }
    public void setToBeClosedResult(String toBeClosedResult) {
        this.toBeClosedResult = toBeClosedResult;
    }
    
    public String getIncidentId() {
        return incidentId;
    }
    public void setIncidentId(String incidentId) {
        this.incidentId = incidentId;
    }
    public boolean getToBeClosed() {
        return toBeClosed;
    }
    public void setToBeClosed(boolean toBeClosed) {
        this.toBeClosed = toBeClosed;
    }
    public short getCloseStatusCode() {
        return closeStatusCode;
    }
    public void setCloseStatusCode(short closeStatusCode) {
        this.closeStatusCode = closeStatusCode;
    }
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
    public Integer getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }
    public void setCommentId(Integer commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }
    public String getCommentType() {
        return commentType;
    }
    public void setCommentType(String commentType) {
        this.commentType = commentType;
    }
    public List<AggregatedHoldListResource> getAutoHolds() {
        return autoHolds;
    }
    public void setAutoHolds(List<AggregatedHoldListResource> autoHolds) {
        this.autoHolds = autoHolds;
    }
    public List<AggregatedHoldListResource> getManualHolds() {
        return manualHolds;
    }
    public void setManualHolds(List<AggregatedHoldListResource> manualHolds) {
        this.manualHolds = manualHolds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using to JSON processing?

Comment: for Jackson annotate your method with `@JsonGetter`

Comment: Whatever is standard with Spring. How do I check that ?

Comment: @Lino but it is working fine without it for all the other variables. How do I know which library I have ?

Comment: `isToBeClosedResult()` is only a valid getter name for a **`boolean`** data type. Since field `toBeClosedResult` is a `String`, the getter *must* be named `getToBeClosedResult()`

Answer (score 2):

Spring use `Jackson` as a standard `JSON` library and till the end, it doesn't know what is the actual type of your variable. So basically it uses Java Code Conventions where all getters start with `get`

Check this link: [Naming convention for getters/setters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java)

You can use `@JsonAlias` which defines one or more alternative names for a property to be accepted during deserialization i.e. setting JSON data to Java object.

Or `@JsonProperty` to define logical property. `@JsonProperty` can be annotated at non-static setter or getter method or non-static object field. The logical property is used in serialization and de-serialization of JSON. `@JsonProperty` is annotated as following.

For example, you can do smth like that:

```
@JsonProperty("toBeClosed") 
public Boolean isToBeClosedResult() {
   return toBeClosed;
}
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Antaaaa