# default Jackson naming strategy for fields with short names

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I've used Jackson for years, and I am not sure I ever faced this issue.

Using Jackson 2.12.5 in a Spring Boot 2.5.5 project, I have an object that I need to serialize. I have no issue with other fields, but these 2 fields are causing me problems :

```
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Getter
public class ComputationResult {
  
  private final String pId;

  private final String cId;

  ... other fields ignored

}
```

As you can see, I am also using Lombok annotations. When "delombokized", the getters are :

```
  public String getPId() {
    return this.pId;
  }

  public String getCId() {
    return this.cId;
  }
```

when serializing the POJO, I expect the field names to be "pId" and "cId", but they are not : I get "pid" and "cid", all lower-case. I don't have the problem with other fields, for which the case is respected.

It caused me an issue because I need to serialize then deserialize the POJO, and the deserialization failed because it could not map "cid" json field to "cId" java field.

There are various workarounds (I am using `@JsonAlias("cid")` on the field to allow the deserialization), but I am puzzled : is this an expected behavior by Jackson ? does it process String fields differently depending on their length ? or is it a java beans convention that I am not aware of ?

Is there a property to set in the objectMapper to "fix" the behavior, without implementing my own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by how JavaBeans methods get generated when there's a single lowercase character at the beginning of the property name.  You might be surprised by the fact that [`getpId` and `getcId` are indeed correctly named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java), just as I was.

In short, `pId` correctly results in the getter `getpId` rather than the Lombok-generated `getPId` (the one JavaBeans should have kept, in my opinion).

Now, the interesting part is that Jackson makes `cid` and `pid` out of `getCId` and `getPId`, respectively, for some reason... while at the same time producing `cId` and `pId` for `getcId` and `getpId`.

So while `getcId` and `getpId` are a quirk of JavaBeans, it seems that Jackson is behaving correctly by default, when the getters are correctly named, i.e., `getpId -> "pId"` and `getcId -> "cId"`.

Given that Lombok generates `getPId` and `getCId`, which lead to the all-lowercase keys in the resulting JSON, deserialization does not work.

If you don't like the `getpId`/`getcId` naming, then you may have to write your own getters and force a property name explicitly:

```
@Builder
@Jacksonized
class ComputationResult {

    private final String pId;
    private final String cId;

    @JsonProperty("pId")
    public String getPId() {
        return pId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cId")
    public String getCId() {
        return cId;
    }
}
```

For the setters, you already have to rely on `@Jacksonized` because of `final` fields anyway, so it doesn't make a difference. Just note that `@Getter` has to be omitted because it'd result in duplicate properties (with the other kind of naming, that is).