# Why xxId can be assigned value and xId can not in Spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot

I define a request

```java
package com.example.demo.demos.service;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CreateRequest {
    private String name;
    private String xId;
    private String xxId;
}
```

then pass params

```json
{
    "xId": "zzz",
    "xxId": "aaa",
    "name": "test"
}
```

why xId is null when i get the value

```
CreateRequest(name=test, xId=null, xxId=aaa)
```

controller code as below

```java
package com.example.demo.demos.web;

import com.example.demo.demos.service.CreateRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test(@RequestBody CreateRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request);
    }
}
```

only happen when first letter is lowercase

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example? like how the controller is implemented, how are you mapping if you are, etc. so that others can also try to reproduce your issue locally and help you better

Comment: create project use spring boot initializr,and i put the controller code in the question

Comment: Use ObjectMapper to write the CreateRequest as String: `{"name":"test","xid":"aaa","xxId":"bbb"}`, but turn to use record then it works well `{"name":"test","xId":"aaa","xxId":"bbb"}`. So now we know which way is preferable for DTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted your example in the question and turns out for me everything was coming as `null`. Not sure how it is partially working for you.

The reason why it did not work for me was because the `CreateRequest` class did not have getter and setters, so it will not be possible to set the values when the `request` is received... after adding all the getters/setters I was able to get all the values including `xId`

### Edit

Since you are using `@Data` annotation, it autogenerates getters/setters in the naming format:

```
getName(), setName()
getXId(), setXId()
getXxId(), setXxId()
```

Problem with this naming convention is that it will expect `xid` and `xxId` as the property name while deserialization. Hence the following json will work:

```json
{
    "xid": "zzz",
    "xxId": "aaa",
    "name": "test"
}
```

It is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100702/default-jackson-naming-strategy-for-fields-with-short-names)

If you want it to still follow the property name as `xId` then you can specify it using the following annotation:

```java
@JsonProperty("xId")
private String xId;
```

Comment: sorry, i use @Data annotation, i add the code in the question

Comment: edited my answer to explain why it is not working with @Data annotation